# Delete the repetoire tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[repetoire](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repetoire) is a misspelling of [repertoire](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repertoire), and I don't think it should be kept even if it is a synonym.

Comment: I thought that the repetoire was a clever use of synonyms by the moderators (Rebecca?) for non-french people. What bad consequences could that have?

Comment: @ogerard It's spelled the same way in English. I don't see any problems arising from it, but misspellings are usually deleted.  To encourage the correct spelling, I suppose.  It was proposed by another mod, Dori.

Comment: it is spelled the same but frenchmen pronounce distinctly the second "r"  :-).

Comment: I agree that `repetoire` should be deleted (I was the one that deleted it from the first post where it showed up and replaced it with the correct spelling). If someone wants to tag a post `repertoire` but doesn't know how to spell the word, the correct spelling will pop up when they type the first few letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the tag synonym.  Since [repetoire](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repetoire) doesn't exist, it isn't currently being displayed in the tag auto-completion list.  If the tag does come back and ends up being a common misspelling, then I would suggest creating the tag synonym again.  Until then, the tag synonym would seem to only encourage the misspelling.